# Show number without exponential expression after remove non-numeric character

Tags: excel, vba

I have the following code to remove some "garbage" from cell contents.

```
Sub RemoveChar()
With Cells
    Cells.NumberFormat = "@" ' setting format as text
    Cells.Replace What:="#", Replacement:=""
End With
End Sub
```

The sheet contains values like `#123451234512345` and when I remove the `#` the value changes to look like this `1.23451E+14` even when above I changed the format to text before the replacement.

How can I remove the character `#` and after remove it say to Excel to show the value as `123451234512345` and not as `1.23451E+14`?

Thank in advance.

Comment: You can try replacing it with a single quote (`'`)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this : (Change 'ActiveCell' to your needs)

```
ActiveCell.NumberFormat = "0"
```